# Autocomplete from Materialize CSS not working (Javascript + Google Apps Script)

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, autocomplete, materialize

I have written the following code in Google Apps Script. My HTML code is using the Autocomplete from Materialize.css
However, the autocomplete is not running. I take the data for autocomplete from a google sheet with ID menioned below.

The html head contains a lot of Bootstrap CDN and Materialize CDN. Initially I thought that the autocomplete is not working because of conflicting CDNs. But that doesn't seem to be the case.

Please help me.

```
  </script>
 document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){     
 google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(populateCodes).getCodes(); });

function populateCodes(words)
{
  var autocomplete = document.getElementById("InputCode");
  var instances = M.Autocomplete.init(autocomplete,{data : words});
}

function FilterTables() {
  var input, filter, table, tr, td, i;
  input = document.getElementById("InputCode");
  filter = input.value;
  table = document.getElementById("myTable");
  tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
  for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
    td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[1];
    if (td) {
      if (td.innerHTML.indexOf(filter) > -1) {
        tr[i].style.display = "";
      } else {
        tr[i].style.display = "none";
      }
    }       
  }
}
function getCodes()
{
  var id = "1L33jDRFmDxEf3Q-RYR8uyQe6IVkSDkSU09YKusZ_8Gw";
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(id);
  var wsData = ss.getSheetByName("Data");
  var RetCodes = wsData.getRange(2, 2,wsData.getRange('B2').getDataRegion().getLastRow(),1).getValues();
  var options = {};
  var CodesR = RetCodes.map(function(o){return o[0];})
  RetCodes.forEach(function(v)
                   {
    options[v[0]] = null;

                    });
  return options;

  }
  </script>


<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
         <meta charset="utf-8">
           <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
            <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
              <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">
                <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
                <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
              <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
            <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
          <script src="https://www.w3schools.com/lib/w3.js"></script>
        <script src="https://www.w3schools.com/lib/w3.js"></script>
            <?!= include("page-css"); ?> 
  </head>
<body>
 <?!= include("page-js"); ?>
    <div class="row"> 
       <div class = "container">
          <div class="input-field col s3">
             <i class="material-icons prefix">textsms</i>
                <input type="text" id="InputCode"  style="width: auto alignment: center" >
                <label id = "InputLabel" for="InputCode"></label>  
             <input id='RClick' type='button' name='button' value='Details' onclick="FilterTables()">
          </div>
       </div>
    </div> 

    <div class = "container">
       <div class="input-field col s8">
          <table id="myTable">
            <?!= tablecells ?> 
          </table>
       </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

For starters - you are missing the classname `.autocomplete`. This is pretty crucial - it is the class that Materialize uses to turn a regular input into an autocomplete.

```
<input type="text" id="InputCode"  style="width: auto alignment: center" >
```

Always use the markup from the [docs](https://materializecss.com/autocomplete.html) until you're comfortable freestyling.

[Pen](https://codepen.io/doughballs/pen/PoPKrEN) to demo the importance of the classname.

Comment: I have tried to input classname and select the class using querySelector to select the autocomplete class. 
It still doesn't work
I had taken reference from this video - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GhAmyLukD6o to learn the way to do this

Comment: You don't have to querySelector the classname to get it to work - but you MUST have the classname on the element otherwise Materialize has no idea that it is an autocomplete el. You can still grab it by ID - but it has to have the class.

Comment: Even after adding a classname it is not working. How should I make progress now? What else could be missing?

Comment: Any console errors? And the init runs AFTER the autocomplete is added to the dom?